# Fastest way to get histogram of array sizes using MongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get a list of the number of records that have arrays of varying size.  I want to get the distribution of array sizes for all records so I can build a histogram like this:

```
          | *
          | *
documents | *         *
          | *  *      *
          |_*__*__*___*__*___
            2  5  6  23  47

               Array Size
```

So the raw documents look something like this:

```js
{hubs : [{stuff:0, id:6}, {stuff:1"}, .... ]}
{hubs : [{stuff:0, id:6}]}`
```

So far using the aggregation framework and some of the help [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) I've come up with

```js
db.sitedata.aggregate([{ $unwind:'$hubs'}, 
                       { $group : {_id:'$_id', count:{$sum:1}}}, 
                       { $group : {_id:'$count', count:{$sum:1}}},
                       { $sort  : {_id: 1}}])
```

This seems to give me the results I want, but it's not very fast.  I'm wondering if there is something I can do like this that may not need two group calls.  The syntax is wrong here, but what I'm trying to do is put the count value in the first _id field:

```js
db.sitedata.aggregate([{ $unwind:'$hubs'}, 
                       { $group : {_id:{$count:$hubs}, count:1}},
                       { $sort  : { _id: 1 }}])
```

Comment: there isn't a way to do this in one pass because you can't start counting/grouping the results until you finish counting the first grouping.  What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: by the way, how long is it taking?

Comment: Ok, I suspected that may be the case (nesting not allowed, only chaining).  It is taking about 4 seconds, which isn't too bad but I was hoping sub second.  I can tweak my data instead of tweaking the query now.

Comment: right, one approach to speed this up would be to pre-aggregate sums by doing increments of a counter when you push new elements, though there may be other ones - how many documents do you have going into the pipeline (and is it the full collection or are you doing some sort of a $match first?)

Comment: I'm doing no $match first because it's a reference data rollup.  It's only about 60,000 records, but quite a bit of pipeline processing.  I agree that adding a count to the record is probably the best option for speeding up the query by removing one of the $group's in the pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that 2.6 is out, aggregation framework supports a [new array operator `$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) which will allow you to `$project` the array size without having to unwind and re-group.

```
db.sitedata.aggregate([{ $project:{ 'count': { '$size':'$hubs'} } }, 
                       { $group : {_id:'$count', count:{$sum:1} } },
                       { $sort  : { _id: 1 } } ] )
```